# Why is the following conversion from using fwrite() to write() on sockets failing?

Tags: c, linux

I am using gcc on linux.

I was previously using the following code : 

    `ret = fread(entry, sizeof *entry, 1, (FILE *)fp);
    if (ret != 1) {
      ASSERT(feof((FILE *)fp));
      entry->type = RR_ENTRY_TYPE_INVALID;
      return;
    }
    ASSERT(entry->ebufsize <= size);
    if (entry->ebufsize) {
      ret = fread(buf, 1, entry->ebufsize, (FILE *)fp);
      ASSERT(ret == entry->ebufsize);
    }`

and I changed it to the following :

`ret = read(connFD_rr, entry, sizeof *entry);
    if( ret!=sizeof *entry) {
      ASSERT(feof((FILE *)fp));
      entry->type = RR_ENTRY_TYPE_INVALID;
      return;
    }
    ASSERT(entry -> ebufsize <= size);
    if(entry->ebufsize) {
      ret = read(connFD_rr, buf, entry->ebufsize);
      ASSERT(ret == entry->ebufsize);
    }`

originally fp was obtained by doing `fdopen(connFD_rr)`

The corresponding writes are as follows :

The fwrite version : 

    `int ret;
    ret = fwrite(entry, sizeof *entry, 1, (FILE *)fp);
    ASSERT(ret == 1);
    if (entry->ebufsize) {
      ret = fwrite(buf, 1, entry->ebufsize, (FILE *)fp);
      ASSERT(ret == entry->ebufsize);
    }`

The write() version : 

    `int ret = write(connFD_rr, entry, sizeof *entry);
    ASSERT(ret == sizeof *entry);
    if(entry->ebufsize) {
      ret = write(connFD_rr, buf, entry->ebufsize);
      ASSERT (ret == entry->ebufsize);
    }
  }`

The new version works for some time before the assertion `ret == sizeof *entry` fails.

Is there something obviously wrong with how have changed the usage ?

What could be causing the problem ?

Comment: Try printing `strerr(errno)` when the assertion fails.

Comment: @larsmans Do you mean printing errno to stderr ?

Comment: Yes, or rather its string representation. That gives you an idea of what went wrong.

Comment: `perror("error:");` should be enough

Comment: Then @glglgl's answer is correct; you got an `EAGAIN` error. See `write(2)`.

Comment: How do I open man page for write(2) in the terminal ? when i write `man write` it opens a different man page..

Comment: @larsmans the error is "Interrupted system call" and not EAGAIN ( I think they are differnt ?)

Comment: `man 2 write`. And yes, those are different, I believe "Interrupted system call" is `EINTR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIR `fwrite()` tries to ensure that complete records are written. As each record has `sizeof *entry` bytes, the given entry is written as a whole or not at all.

`write()`, however, is happy with writing 1 byte. If the buffer is full then, it returns, telling you that it has written 1 byte. Depending on how large `sizeof *entry` is, this happens often or seldom.

Comment: okay .. is there any way to ensure that the complete record is read ?

Comment: Yeah, keep `read()`ing at the proper offset until you've read enough.

Comment: Yes, read and write should always be called in a loop until all the data you want has been received/sent. Many times you only go through the loop once, but not always.

Comment: This is exactly what was happening with me ! I followed the advise of Dave to make it work